# Как проверить валидность файла .yml

Tags: drupal, drupal8

Создал файл с форматом .yml но почему то не работает rounting и по адресу указанной страницы вижу 404 ошибку. Как проверить верно ли я заполнил файл по формату .yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы проверить валидность формата файла нужно сналача подключить класc который будет использоваться для расшифрования фомата .yml

```
use Drupal\Component\Serialization\Yaml;
```

Потом просто использовать его метод

```
Yaml::decode(file_get_contents($file)) ;
```

В результате можно увидеть и проверить нет ли какого то пробела лишнего.